# Fatal error: Call to a member function check_user() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\TugasWeb2\application\controllers\login.php on line 43

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

whats wrong with my code ?

```
$count=$this->db_ecommerce->check_user($user, $pswd)->num_rows(); <-- this line 43
```

---

```
        $user=$this->input->post('username');
        $pswd=$this->input->post('password').$this->config->item("key_login");
        //$pswd=$this->input->post('password');
        $count=$this->db_ecommerce->check_user($user, $pswd)->num_rows();
        if($count>0) {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('status_login', 'ok');
            redirect('member');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

before you get the num_rows() you should check if there is any result:

```
 $count = $this->db_ecommerce->check_user($user,$pswd);
 if($count){
     $count = $count->num_rows();
 }
 else{
     $count = 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have already a model with db_ecommerce as name, you should try loading it :

```
$this->load->model('db_ecommerce');
$count=$this->db_ecommerce->check_use ...
```